# Is it possible to use code from a Web project in C# Interactive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c#-interactive

I would like to use C# Interactive on Visual Studio 2017 to run some methods on classes in an .NET Framework 4.6.1 project I have created which uses ASP.NET Core.  In a traditional class library project, I am able to right-click on the project and choose *Initialize Interactive with Project* to use classes from my project in the C# Interactive window.

Right-clicking on my ASP.NET Core project, I do not have this option. Is there any way to use classes from this project in C# Interactive?

If it matters, the classes I would like to use in C# Interactive do not directly interact with ASP.NET Core; they are simply data containers with methods. It would probably be possible to move them to a separate class library project in the solution, but I'd like to know if it's possible to keep them in the ASP.NET Core project first.

My `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" Version="3.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorEngine" Version="3.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: This may be helpful [Interactive-Walkthrough](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open C# interactive window and type

```
#r "full path to dll\exe with your asp.net core project"
```

Then you can use your classes as usual.

Note that if your project targets .NET Core - it might not work as expected (or at all), because as far as I know - C# interactive currently runs under full .NET Framework. However, in your case your project is also under full .NET (`<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`) so you should be fine.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I knew that `#r` accepted DLLs, but I never knew it worked with EXEs. I need to wait 18 hours to award the bounty, but I will award then. (@ me if I forget!)

Comment: @AaronChristiansen maybe you also didn't know then that you can reference exe files in regular .net projects too (of course if that .exe is .net executable).

Comment: No I didn't - that's pretty cool! Am I correct in thinking that they'd have to be built with Debug rather than Release to maintain their symbols and allow interoperability?

Comment: @AaronChristiansen exe is basically the same as dll, but has an entry point method. So there is no difference whether you reference exe or dll - you can use all stuff in referenced library the same way (at least in .NET)

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks. I should learn more about low-level Windows!

Comment: Confirmed what @Evk said. This currently only works under full .NET Framework. No .NET Core support at the time.